# HTML5 web workers for binding jQuery events (what about IE?)

Tags: javascript, multithreading, html

HTML5 workers is a very interesting concept for avoiding a locked up user-interface.

For a shop application I'm listing a larger amount of product-widgets for which I have to activate functionality, using jQuery bindings.

Would I be able to use web workers to perform this task so that the page will responsive much sooner?

The support for web workers is lacking in IE but would be be possible to implement/simulate something simular until support arrives?

I found this implementation for IE and older browsers http://code.google.com/p/ie-web-worker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, web workers don't lock the DOM, so using them speeds up rendering.

The only alternative to web workers is using a succession of short functions called with window.setTimeout, but this will lock the DOM.

edit:
the ie alternative you found isn't quite the same. Because it doesn't perform pre-emptive multitasking (how can it), if you run a long running script the browser will think the page had crashed whereas it wouldn't in chrome, firefox etc.

So basically, because you need to access the DOM. Split your tasks up into fairly large parts (50ms at most) then put each part in a window.setTimeout and let the browser schedule them. If the parts are too small the browser will waste time.

Comment: From MDN: "Note: As usual, background threads—including workers—cannot manipulate the DOM.  If actions taken by the background thread need to result in changes to the DOM, they should post messages back to their creators to do that work.". 

So $('#id').click(functin(){});  will not affect the DOM?

Comment: I didn't realise you wanted to manipulate the DOM. No you can't do anything in a web worker other than processing and posting back messages. There would be no point creating Web Workers that could manipulate the DOM, because DOM access has to be single threaded.

Comment: But would adding a say click event binding be a DOM manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

Web workers will be useful if you're doing long running scripts.  Offloading long running scripts to a "worker" process will keep your UI responsive, as the worker won't block your UI.  Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any great shims / polyfills for web workers for IE (unless the IE user has Google Gears installed).  I've found that the best way to keep your app responsive is to use web workers for browsers that support it, but degrade to using setTimeout (about every 100ms) for browsers that don't.

If you're interested in the Google Gears based shim, here it is: http://html5-shims.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/workers.html

Comment: Yes it would be easy if everyone installed Chrome Frame, FTW. Until then I think the setTimeout solution is the way to go for IE. The link I posed above uses a timeout of 1ms, it seems a bit low don't you think?

Comment: it doesn't matter how long the timeout is so long as there is one. That is the minimum it will wait, it may decide to do another job before returning control to you.

Comment: But I guess there is some overhead running the code. So you have to weigh between blocking with big values (for setTimeout) and the overhead with a lot of function calls with small values (for setTimeout) - or is this just theoretical (well the big value-part is practical enough)